# Google cloud connections networking hotspot ip address

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

So when using google cloud I can not access the sql database when using a hotspot device. I go to sql connections networking and I can put in both my computer's and phone ipv4 address and it won't work. I can use a standard internet connection ipv4 no problem but sometimes I am on the go and need to use hotspot data. Has anyone come across this issue and resolved it?

Comment: If you are using a hotspot, most likely your IP address is a NAT IP address, which is local to the hotspot network. WARNING, unless you have enabled client SSL on Cloud SQL, your login credentials are sent in the clear. Use the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy to solve both the IP address issue and to encrypt your credentials.